# How to prioritize rabbitmq messages in php?

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq

I'm using `RabbitMQ (3.8.3 Erlang 22.3.1)` for `Laravel (6.18.*)`.
For this I'm using, https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq.

With normal queue and consumer, everything is working fine.
To prioritize messages, I've defined multiple queues with 0-3 as suffix in the queue names. I'm routing the jobs to different queues by manually calculating the total jobs.

Using this approach, for different tasks, I needed to create more queues with priorities on the name. Creating queues with 0-3 in the queue names does not seem scalable.

Now I'm trying to set priority per message. For that I tried to use `priority` property in `AMQPMessage` as:

```php
$msg = new AMQPMessage("Hello World!", array(
    'delivery_mode' => 2,
    'priority' => 1,
    'timestamp' => time(),
    'expiration' => strval(1000 * (strtotime('+1 day midnight') - time() - 1))
));
```

I tried multiple messages with different priorities but priority doesn't seem to work at all.

- I set `x-max-priority` on queue
- I set `priority` to 1 for a AMQPMessage and dispatched 100K message from one terminal
- Same time I dispatched another set of message of 10 with `priority` 2

But the consumer doesn't seem to consume message with priority 2.

Any idea what mistake am I doing? Please let me know if there's anything to set priorities per message so that consumer picks them first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use set, like that:

```
$headers = new AMQPTable([
    'x-cache-ttl' => 10 * 60000,
]);

$msg = new AMQPMessage($msg);
$msg->set('application_headers', $headers);
$msg->set('priority', 2);
```

And don't forget to declare queue with 'x-max-priority'

```
$options = new AMQPTable([
    'x-max-priority' => 3,
]);

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(RABBIT_HOST, RABBIT_PORT, RABBIT_LOGIN, RABBIT_PASS);
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('queue_name', false, false, false, false, false, $options);
```